# I expect the initial view controller of my storyboard to be the current controller

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

If the application was previously in the background, when `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called, I expect the initial view controller of my storyboard to be the current controller.

I used:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

When I restart app ,`loginAciton` inside `rootViewController` still be called ,but could not present the next controller . No errors like nothing happened.

```
- (IBAction)loginAciton:(id)sender
{
    id controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Navigation"];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];   
}
```

Why?

PS. My rootViewController is not a UINavigationController.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: What is returned by `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Navigation"]`?

Comment: Can you use `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` instead?

Comment: return UINavigationController. Any differences between `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and `presentModalViewController` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear, use the Debugger or NSLog() and get the actual return value. If `-presentModalViewController:animated:` is failing, then a UINavigationController object is not being returned. `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` and `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` use different identifiers. If you are having problems with one identifier, then the other might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much better way is to add `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to your `Info.plist` and set it to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it !

if you wanna the initial view controller of your storyboard to be the current controller every time , you can try it :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: They might reject your app if you call exit(), mavrick3's suggestion is a bit cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can use the notification too, put this code in  *applicationDidBecomeActive:*

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"appActivated" object:nil];
```

and add observer in that current view ...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(updateView:)        
                                         name:@"appActivated" 
                                       object:nil];
```

and don't forget to remove the observer in *dealloc:* of your current view...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

may this will help you..